# Wxpython Flashing LED indication

Tags: python, wxpython

I am building an application working on BLE, and i would like to make a flashing LED (BLUE) that shows that connection is established.
How can i make an array of flashing LED's for indication?

Any example, reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can already manage to display a bitmap image using wxPython.  What you are going to need is two images.  One for the LED when unlit, and another for the lit LED.

Then, use a wx.Timer to time out the flashing interval, say 500ms.  When the timer elapses, you swap the images.

You may also want to check out [wx.lib.throbber](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.throbber.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number of simple `StaticBox`'s to do the job

```
import wx
import random
blues=['#0000ff','#4682b4','#00008b','#00bfff','#0d4f60']
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Led')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.led1 =  wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", size=(20,20), pos=(10,10))
        self.led2 =  wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", size=(20,20), pos=(31,10))
        self.led3 =  wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", size=(20,20), pos=(52,10))
        self.led4 =  wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", size=(20,20), pos=(73,10))
        self.led5 =  wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", size=(20,20), pos=(94,10))
        self.led1.SetBackgroundColour(blues[0])
        self.led2.SetBackgroundColour(blues[1])
        self.led3.SetBackgroundColour(blues[2])
        self.led4.SetBackgroundColour(blues[3])
        self.led5.SetBackgroundColour(blues[4])
        self.counter = -5
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        self.led1.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(blues))
        self.led2.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(blues))
        self.led3.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(blues))
        self.led4.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(blues))
        self.led5.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(blues))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]